# How do I set boolean2 value according only to boolean1 value in a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

The problem is simple:
I have 2 booleans in a Rails User model, let's call it 'param1' and 'param2'. If param1 = true, param2 = true. Can I implement this condition somewhere in the model with 1-2 lines of code?

Comment: Why you even need the second attribute if they are always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using model callbacks.

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
       before_save :set_params2, if: self.param1?

       private

       def set_param2
        self.param2 = true
       end
    end
```